# calling visibility using fragments - Android

Tags: android, fragment, visibility

I have two activities in my project, Activity_one.xml contains the ProgressBar and checkboxes and i know i can call the visibility method from the same activity but i want to implement the visibility method in Activity_two.java. i have heard that it can be done by using fragments but i have no idea how do i do that?

```
progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        updateProgressBars();
    }
});

checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        updateProgressBars();
    }
});
}

public void updateProgressBars() {

  progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

 if (checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox2.isChecked()) {
    progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 } else if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
    progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }

}
```

Comment: The question is how to use fragments?

Comment: maybe, because i am new to fragments